# change all occurence of <I> tag text into italic

Tags: html, xml, xslt

this is my xml

```
    <P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
        <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 8.5pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 7pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'COMIC SANS MS'; FONT-SIZE: 6.7pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">10-Q</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'CURSIVE'; FONT-SIZE:14pt">Hisasdf @ adsfkej % adsfkj-Q</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Edwardian Script ITC'; FONT-SIZE:18pt">Singhaniadf kurmad-Q</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:36pt"><U>anurag arya fateh ali khan-Q</U></SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:12pt"><U>rakesh kumar sinfhania</U></SPAN>
      </P>

    <P style="MARGIN: 0pt">
        <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 18pt">of advisory fees, estimated legal fees, a $0.6</SPAN>
        <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt">million<U> provision for estimated settlement costs associated with shareholder litigation and other 
transition related costs. These amounts are included in the Company?s </U>sults of operations for the three and nine months ended September</SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 18pt">30, 2010,respectively.</SPAN></P>

<P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold"><I>Washington,</I></SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">D.C. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;20549</SPAN>
    <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt"> 
    </SPAN>
</P>

   <I>of advisory fees, estimated legal fees, a $0.6</I>
```

i want to change all the occurence of `<I>`into italic

i also use this line in the match statement  `match="span/p/i"`

and many other's as suggested by google to change text in italic ,but its not working what to do

Comment: Your input XML is invalid according to the W3C standard. You have to embed your elements in some root element.

Comment: @LukaszBaran actually this is just a part of the large XML and i embed this in a root element..

Comment: @Librak: Was my answer useful to you?

Comment: yes @DimitreNovatchev it was somewhat useful if there is large XML then it is not i have change the logic of it to implement this.

Comment: @Librak: That's intriguing... So, what is the problem in your case? The solution is *generic* and replaces any `<I>` with `<i>` -- not depending on the specifics of the XML document. And from all possible transformations that do this, this solution is maybe the most elegant, maintainable and extensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the provided fragment is *not* wellformed XML. What I did to make it into a well-formed XML document was:

1. Wrapped it into a single top `html` element.
2. Replaced all occurencies of the `&nbsp;` entity with the character entity `&#xA0;` (alternatively a small DTD can be prepended, that defines the entity)

**Solution**:

**This most simple transformation** (override of the identity rule):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="I">
  <i>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </i>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any well-formed XML document** (in this example we use the well-formed XML document produced from the provided fragment):

```
<html>
        <P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 8.5pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
                <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 7pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
                <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'COMIC SANS MS'; FONT-SIZE: 6.7pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
                <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">10-Q</SPAN>
                <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'CURSIVE'; FONT-SIZE:14pt">Hisasdf @ adsfkej % adsfkj-Q</SPAN>
                <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Edwardian Script ITC'; FONT-SIZE:18pt">Singhaniadf kurmad-Q</SPAN>
                <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:36pt"><U>anurag arya fateh ali khan-Q</U></SPAN>
                <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:12pt"><U>rakesh kumar sinfhania</U></SPAN>
          </P>

        <P style="MARGIN: 0pt">
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 18pt">of advisory fees, estimated legal fees, a $0.6</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt">million<U> provision for estimated settlement costs associated with shareholder litigation and other
    transition related costs. These amounts are included in the Company?s </U>sults of operations for the three and nine months ended September</SPAN>
        <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 18pt">30, 2010,respectively.</SPAN></P>

    <P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
        <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold"><I>Washington,</I></SPAN>
        <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">D.C. &#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;20549</SPAN>
        <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt">
        </SPAN>
    </P>

       <I>of advisory fees, estimated legal fees, a $0.6</I>

</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (`<I>` is replaced by `<i>`):

```
<html>
   <P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 8.5pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 7pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'COMIC SANS MS'; FONT-SIZE: 6.7pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">10-Q</SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'CURSIVE'; FONT-SIZE:14pt">Hisasdf @ adsfkej % adsfkj-Q</SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Edwardian Script ITC'; FONT-SIZE:18pt">Singhaniadf kurmad-Q</SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:36pt">
         <U>anurag arya fateh ali khan-Q</U>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:12pt">
         <U>rakesh kumar sinfhania</U>
      </SPAN>
   </P>
   <P style="MARGIN: 0pt">
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 18pt">of advisory fees, estimated legal fees, a $0.6</SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt">million<U> provision for estimated settlement costs associated with shareholder litigation and other
    transition related costs. These amounts are included in the Company?s </U>sults of operations for the three and nine months ended September</SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 18pt">30, 2010,respectively.</SPAN>
   </P>
   <P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">
         <i>Washington,</i>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">D.C.     20549</SPAN>
      <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt"/>
   </P>
   <i>of advisory fees, estimated legal fees, a $0.6</i>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the important block called [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="I">
            <i> <xsl:value-of select="."/></i>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT** - Some clarification:

I have applied my XSLT to the following XML. Note that I added `<body></body>`, as according to the W3C standard XML can have only one [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).

```
<body>
<P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 8.5pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">
            <I>Form tesindf is the good one m trying it</I>
            </SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 8.5pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold"><I>Form tesindf is the good one m trying it</I></SPAN>
        </P>
<I>of advisory fees, estimated legal fees, a $0.6</I>
</body>
```

Comment: Which XSLT engine are you using? What's the output?

Comment: using xslt 1.0 and this code snippet only wrks for the given code but if i add more text in the XML than this will not wrks...

Comment: ur code wrks fine in the XML u supposed but its not wrking in the XML i m using...

PLEASE SEE MY EDITED XML...ON which i m wrking